# How do I upgrade Magento 2.4 using composer?

Tags: magento2, upgrade

How do I upgrade Magento 2.4 using composer to e.g. Magento 2.4.1 or Magento 2.4.2 or Magento 2.4.3 for that matter?

We've been reading https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

But every time we run into problems with missing modules and similar issues. Also the guide is a 'catch all situations guide' like moving from community ot enterprise and v.v. --

We just want to move from 2.4 to 2.4.1

Would this be the following, clear concise or can it be better?

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3-p1 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento maintenance:disable
service varnish restart #(optional, often can only be done by root)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sequence to run for a minor update from Magento 2.4 using composer to e.g. Magento 2.4.1 or Magento 2.4.2 or Magento 2.4.3

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3-p1 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

(optional, these often can only be done by root)

```
service php-fpm restart
service nginx restart
service varnish restart
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the Below Commands,**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0

composer update

bin/magento s:up

bin/magento s:s:d -f

bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded today from 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3.

Here is what I did:

1.

```
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
```

2. 

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 --no-update
```

3. Then removed the **replace section** of my composer.json

If you don't do this, it might brick your install. I had to roll back my setup from a backup because it completely destroyed it.

4. Update this section to the one you are updating to:

   'version': '2.4.3

This was throwing composer errors if I didn't change it.

5. Then just

   composer update

   rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*

   bin/magento setup:upgrade

   bin/magento setup:di:compile

   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

   bin/magento cache:flush